# Relative Height size with a max-height

Tags: height, fluid-layout, css

I am trying to set a height to be relative to the size of the screen (height = 12%), but I don't want it to exceed a certain pixel height (i.e. max-height: 150px). What is the proper css for this. I have tried:

```
.titleBar {
    position: relative; 
    background-color: #5C755E; 
    padding: 1%; 
    height: 12%; 
    max-height: 100px; 
    border-bottom: .45em solid #DEB887; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

but this ignores the max-height property. On my large desktop screen the titlebar becomes 200px (much too big).

Comment: Another drive-by downvote, no explanation. I wish stack overflow would address this problem of downvoting without any explanation as to why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use min-height instead of height. Height overrides min and max height unless set to auto. Combination of height and min-height (unless height:auto) ignores min/max height.

This should work.

```
.titleBar {
    position: relative; 
    background-color: #5C755E; 
    padding: 1%; 
    min-height: 12%; 
    max-height: 100px; 
    border-bottom: .45em solid #DEB887; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a height to your parent element, if you have one. So if you add a height to the parent element of 432px, the div will now be at a height of 36px.

Also, a few notes.

- You should choose to use either ems or pixels. Don't use both.
- If you add the property border-box to the element, the width will show up as 100% of the page, not 100% of the page, and then add the padding, so it turns out to be slightly more.
- You might want to add a min-height also.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Cody, However, I want the design to be fluid (using relative measurements like ems), but I don't want the title bar to be any bigger than 125px (the full size of the logo image is 100px so it doesn't scale well). There is no-where on the site right now that uses pixels, I just want to restrict that one height property so, on large screens, it doesn't get way bigger than the image logo.

Comment: Well I hope this helped. I think its what you want.

Comment: thanks for the help and I will give you a plus 1, but it doesn't resolve my problem. I need to be able to set a relative height (12%), a max-height that is concrete (125px) inside an element who's parent is set with a relative height (33%). Thanks for your help though.